# Rearranging the html tables based on condition using react

Tags: reactjs

I am getting values from API in JSON format. I have used the map and iterated it and displayed it on the screen using an HTML table. I want to arrange the table based on the condition that I have.

Here is the screenshot of my work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAJof.jpg

The code is mentioned below.

I want the violet div to be shown at the top and below that the right answer div

React Code:

```
                          {akey===3?<div>{answer.body} hope one answer</div>:""}
                          <div className={'answer'+(parseInt(question.answer) === answer.id ? ' selected' : '')}>
                         <span className="successtick">{answer.right?<Icon icon="small-tick" intent="success"/>:<Icon icon="cross" intent="danger"/> }</span> 
                          { answer.body }
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td className="col badges">
                          {answer.right ? <span className="badge correct">correct answer</span> : ''}
                          {parseInt(question.answer) === answer.id ? 
                          <span className="badge your"> your answer</span> : ''}
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should re-arrange your data list coming from the api according to the order or condition you want and when you do your map, the `<td />`s in the table will render in that order